# Shopify Brooklyn theme : changes not reflected

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am still on shopify trial period.

I have made one change in shopify theme but changes are not getting reflected.

Is it due to trial that changes are not getting reflected. I want to add credit card icons in footer.

Comment: Did you try force refreshing (`Ctrl+Shift+R`), or clearing cache?. Maybe it's because the cached version.

Answer (score 1):

Shopify trials will not limit your ability to modify themes in any circumstance at all. We can't really tell from the outside but some things that could be happening to you are...

1. Browser cache. You're still viewing your old assets files instead of your updated ones. Make sure to force refresh `Shift-Command-R` on OSX or `Ctrl+Shift+R` on Windows.
2. Not saving the files. If you have a Liquid error on your file, Shopify won't save the file and will instead tell you there's been an error.
3. Modifying the wrong theme. Make sure you're either modifying the published theme, or previewing the theme you're modifying.
4. Modifying the wrong file. Some themes are packed up with alternatives and variations of the different sections. The one you're modifying may not be the one that is actually getting rendered on the site.

Hope that helps!